# К знатокам пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, нужны ли запятые в этих предложениях. Желательно с пояснениями. Заранее спасибо.
1. В нас никто не верил. А мы верили и у нас получилось.(интересует второе предложение).
2. Только искренне любя музыку можно открывать ее тайну другим.

Answer (score 1):

Согласна с предыдущим ответом, но хочется добавить. Во-первых, "**В нас** никто не верил. А мы верили **(в кого? в нас? )** ,и у нас получилось" Во-вторых, почему точка перед союзом а? Я бы исправила так: "В нас никто не верил, а мы верили в себя - и у нас получилось!" (Тире как интонационное, или как перед предложением, в котором неожиданный результат)

Comment: Верили в нас, в себя...
Точка перед а, так как результат есть следствие одной только веры в себя, без неверия других))
Тогда можно и так и так написать? :
В нас никто не верил. А мы верили - и у нас получилось.
В нас никто не верил. А мы верили, и у нас получилось.

Answer (score 0):

"А мы верили, и у нас получилось". В этом предложении нужна запятая перед сочинительным союзом "И", потому что данное предложение является сложным и имеет в своем составе две предикативные единицы.
"Только искренне любя музыку, можно открывать ее тайну другим". Здесь также ставится запятая, но уже по другой причине. Несмотря на то, что деепричастный оборот с безличными конструкциями не употребляется здесь он вполне уместен:он выполняет функцию условия.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Хотя мне казалось, можно было обойтись без запятых... Особенно во втором предложении. То есть, напр., в таком предложении тоже нужна была бы запятая?
Можно победить, только веря в свою победу.
Да?

Answer (score 0):

А можно и так:
В нас никто не верил. А мы верили. И у нас получилось.

А вот в предложении *Можно победить только веря в свою победу*, на мой взгляд, запятая не нужна. Здесь налицо тесное слияние деепричастного оборота со сказуемым.

Answer (score 0):

```
А мы верили, и у нас получилось. Запятая стоит МЕЖДУ двумя простыми предложениями в составе сложного. Запятая - это пауза, она всегда МЕЖДУ чем-то и чем-то. Опасная привычка ставить её "перед союзами" приводит к путанице и нарушению логического восприятия.

Что касается второго предложения, то там НЕ НУЖНА запятая, это часть сказуемого, отвечает на вопросы - как? каким образом?
```